linux + wipe a signature from a device not succeeded
we have the following file system.
from lsblk -f
sdb                 LVM2_member       uMrU0b-6F3l-M9Ue-LPsf-kd6n-5l4m-WfxaRQ
└─DB_vg-DB_lv xfs                     a800d759-c8c7-4e7e-86d5-3d6a06123465
sdc                 LVM2_member       CgGp4m-qGtE-S3Br-0gJs-IdCG-CJXM-pwu7ps
└─DB_vg-DB_lv xfs                     a800d759-c8c7-4e7e-86d5-3d6a06123465
sdd                 LVM2_member       vGfMF3-PPem-JOjD-w2Qt-bP4O-Wppy-YnIB6A
└─DB_vg-DB_lv xfs                     a800d759-c8c7-4e7e-86d5-3d6a06123465

from lsblk
sdb                   8:16   0    4G  0 disk
└─DB_vg-DB_lv 253:4    0   12G  0 lvm
sdc                   8:32   0    4G  0 disk
└─DB_vg-DB_lv 253:4    0   12G  0 lvm
sdd                   8:48   0    4G  0 disk
└─DB_vg-DB_lv 253:4    0   12G  0 lvm

on that disks that isn't mounted we doing the following:
wipefs -a /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd

wipefs: error: /dev/sdb: probing initialization failed: Device or resource busy

why we get Device or resource busy , when disks sdb sdc sdd are not mounted ?
and what is the right approach to wipe fs on that disks

I guess you need to make LVM stop using the devices. Do you want to totally remove (dismantle) the logical volume(s) and the volume group that use the devices? Or do you want to keep them (using/adding other physical volumes) but still "detach" sdb, sdc and sdd?

From wipefs device or resource busy,
combining two answers :

Unmount the disk and all the partitions on it:
sudo umount /dev/sdb*



Use the -f (force) option:
wipefs -af /dev/sdb


